# Core Data: In XCode how can I set my attribute to be unique?

Tags: xcode, core-data, attributes, unique

I'm setting up my Data Model for Core Data and I'm trying to find out how I can set up an attribute to be unique.  I want it so that if another object is about the be saved then it wont allow it if this attribute is the same value as another. How can I do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As specified in the [Validation section of the CoreData guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdValidation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004807-SW5), you can use the key-valu-coding validation patterns described in [the KVC guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/Validation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002173-CJBDBHCB). Specifically, in the [automatic validation section](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/Validation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002173-SW1), it mentions that CoreData will use the KVC validation patterns when it tries to save. So on your model categories, you will end up with something like this:

```
-(BOOL) validateCourseName:(NSString **) courseName error:(NSError **) error {
  // lookup existing course names, return NO if one exists, YES if none.
  // note that courseName is a **, which means you can modify it if that makes sense.
  *courseName = @"new name which will validate";
  // but be sure to read the parts of the linked docs about memory if you do this.
  return YES
}
```

Comment: I think the better place would be to contain the logic in `validateBeforeInsert`. Not certain of the method name though.
I mean this method will be fired every time the value changes. The Uniqueness can be validated before insert or update.

Comment: the method is `validateForInsert:`