# CoreData taking some time before NSFetchRequest finds new objects

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I have a form in my app that allows users to input text and save it to `CoreData` in a `UIManagedDocument`.

While the app is running, I'm using an `NSManagedObjectContext` as the one and only context for inserting and fetching objects from this document.

The problem I have is - before saving I check for duplicates, and if I do subsequent inserts with waiting like **10** seconds, the `context` doesn't acknowledge already inserted (`[matches count]` returns 0) objects, and allows for duplicates.

If on the other hand I wait for some it - the result is as expected (`[matches count]` returns whatever number is true).

#### Code in full

```
@implementation Student (Create)

+ (Student *)withInfo:(NSDictionary *)infoDictionary inManagedContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)context
{
    Student *student = nil;

    // Check for duplicates
    NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Student"];
    request.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"studentID == %@", (NSString *)infoDictionary[@"studentID"]];
    [request includesPendingChanges];

    NSError *error = nil;
    NSArray *matches = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];

    if (!matches || ([matches count] > 1)) {
        // handle error
        NSLog(@"Error happens");
        for (Student *student in matches) {
            [context deleteObject:student];
            NSLog(@"studentID: %@", student.studentID);
        }
    } else if (![matches count]) {
        student = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Student" inManagedObjectContext:context];

        NSString *studentID = (NSString *)infoDictionary[@"studentID"];
        int studentIDint = [studentID intValue];
        NSLog(@"studentID: %d", studentIDint);

        student.studentID = [NSNumber numberWithInt:studentIDint];
        student.nameFirst = infoDictionary[@"nameFirst"];
        student.nameLast  = infoDictionary[@"nameLast"];

        // Add this students portrait as a relationship
        Portrait *portrait = [Portrait portraitWithAssetURL:infoDictionary[@"PortraitAssetURL"] inManagedObjectContext:context];
        student.portrait = portrait;

        NSError *errorSave;
        [context save:&errorSave];
        NSLog(@"errorSave: %@", errorSave);

        NSLog(@"creating a new student, matches count: %lu", (unsigned long)[matches count]);
    } else {
        student = [matches lastObject];
        NSLog(@"fetching old one, count: %lu", (unsigned long)[matches count]);
    }

    return student;
}

@end
```

Comment: Hmmm, this sounds like you are using the same context in multithreaded enviroment "I do subsequent inserts with waiting like 10 seconds", is this true? Cause MOC isn thread safe

Comment: I perform everything on the main thread, and anyhow, when using MOC `performBlock` you always get the same thread as the one MOC is on.

Comment: Is this your exact code? Are you inserting with entity name "EntityName" and fetching with entity name "Student"?

Comment: I dont understand, U should check with setting predicate not sort descriptor, this will only sort all of your results

Comment: @Leijonien Sorry that was a typo, now they both match up. I'm searching within the same entity. Also, added missing predicate (it was always there...)

Comment: How and when is your inserted entity getting an unique ID? Did you also notice you can can a column like 'uniqueID' to be unique in CoreData. This will actually prevent you to be able to insert duplicates.

Comment: @Leijonien where can I mark a column as unique in Xcode?

Comment: It's not really marking, but you can do it in code, see for an example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11386759/core-data-in-xcode-how-can-i-set-my-attribute-to-be-unique.

Comment: Ok U could really trie to give us some more materials to work with, trie posting all of your insert code (with save), and from where U R calling it, U know, little more context, this is trivial stuff that U R doing, it has to be something small that U overlooked... Come on some details :)

Comment: @AntonijoDev Here is the updated, in full, version my current code.

Comment: OK I tried your code and it works great, new IDs are stored in database and the duplicates are not. The only thing I could't reproduce is the portraitWithAssetURL method so i stored nil for portrait relation. I tried waiting, restarting app, and many many other things, it just works. Now if this is all of your relevant code and the only difference is named method, why don't U trie to comment setting Portrait relation, or set it to nil, just for test, and then trie if it works, if that doesn't do it than the problem is somewhere outside this scope ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code should look something like this:

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"EntityName"];
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"uniqueID == %@", newID]
[request setPredicate:predicate];
NSError *error = nil; 
NSArray *matches = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];

if([matches count]){
    // update record
    SomeEnt *ent = [matches objectAtIndex:0];
    // ent set properties  
} 
else{
        // add new record
    SomeEnt *ent =  [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"EntityName" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    // ent set properties 
    // ...
}
NSError *error;
[context save:&error];
```

Comment: It looks Exactly the same.

Comment: Ok didn't see the version with predicate, and U dont need sort

Comment: Does it look like this?

Comment: I think your code is placing `insertNewObjectForEntityForName` in the wrong place, because you would be adding the same object to context independent of the `[matches count]` result. I guess it should be placed inside the `else` block.

Comment: Uuuups sry, that should have been save, I copped the wrong line I will fix

Comment: Thanks for your efforts, alas, they produced no changes.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should call `[context save:&error]` to save your modification to the store.
Or add `[request includesPendingChanges:YES]` to allow request on pending unsaved changes.

Comment: None of these suggestions seem to have any effect. The behaviour is still the same.

Answer (score 0):

Something in your query does not make sense. You are sorting by uniqueID but only fetching one ID, so what is the sort for? Eliminate it.

Also, it does not make sense to check for uniqueID *before saving*. You should instead do this check *before creating* the new object.

This query should be very fast and not interfere with your insert at all. Consider also setting the `fetchLimit` to 1, but this is not really necessary.

```
NSArray *results = [self.managedObjectContext 
                   executeFetchRequest:request error:nil]; 

EntityName *object;
if (results.count) {
   object = results.lastObject;
}
else {
   object = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObject… ];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but your version of how to approach this issue produced the same results.

Comment: Are you iterating in a loop calling these inserts repeatedly? If yes, please show the loop. If no, explain more in detail what you are doing and what the actual problem is.